# Is it possible to have two listoffigures with bicaption?

Tags: table-of-contents, floats, captions, bicaption

Now I'm using Chinese to write a paper. It is required that the caption of the figures should be written in both Chinese and English. I found that this can be realized using `bicaption` package. However, if  bicaption is used, the command `\listoffigures` produces only one list of figures, in which both the English caption and Chinese caption are included. I want to make them separate, namely a list only contains Chinese caption, and a list only contains English caption. The following is my attempt.

```
\documentclass{ctexbook}
\usepackage{caption,bicaption,graphicx}
\captionsetup[figure][bi-second]{name=Figure}
\usepackage{mwe}

\begin{document}
\frontmatter
\listoffigures
\mainmatter
\blindtext
\begin{figure}[!htbp]
    \centering
    \includegraphics{example-image.pdf}
    \bicaption{第一个图}{first figure}
    \label{fig:figure1}
\end{figure}

\blindtext
\begin{figure}[!htbp]
    \centering
    \includegraphics{example-image.pdf}
    \bicaption{第二个图}{second figure}
    \label{fig:figure2}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

In the above code, I use `ctexbook` class file to produce the Chinese document. I think the possible workaround is to redefine the command `\bicaption` so that the English caption can be written into a different file such as `enlof`, rather than mixing with Chinese caption in `lof` file. I'm new to LaTeX and I don't know how to implement it :(

Comment: The bicaption documentation states in section 5 "Customising lists": "Another option is separating the lists. For that purpose the option listtype+=(type extension) can be used to tell the bicaption package to use a different list for the second caption text." -- I haven't tried it out myself but since it is documented (with example document) I assume it is possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems to work like documented in section 5 "Customizing lists" of the bicaption package documentation, i.e. using the option `listtype+=...` for this purpose:

```
\documentclass{ctexbook}
\usepackage{caption,bicaption,graphicx}
\captionsetup[figure][bi-second]{name=Figure}
\usepackage{mwe}

% Use the bicaption package with list type "figureEng" for the 2nd language
\captionsetup[bi-second]{listtype+=Eng}
% Define type "figureEng" and \listoffigureEng
\usepackage{newfloat}
\DeclareFloatingEnvironment[fileext=lof2]{figureEng}[Figure][List of Figures]

\begin{document}
\frontmatter
\listoffigures
\listoffigureEng
\mainmatter
\blindtext
\begin{figure}[!htbp]
    \centering
    \includegraphics{example-image.pdf}
    \bicaption{第一个图}{first figure}
    \label{fig:figure1}
\end{figure}

\blindtext
\begin{figure}[!htbp]
    \centering
    \includegraphics{example-image.pdf}
    \bicaption{第二个图}{second figure}
    \label{fig:figure2}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: This work for my example. Thanks a lot! I should have read the document carefully.